# How to escape % inside double quotes in cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, escaping

In cmd I'm trying to do something like

```
program.exe -command "otherprogram.exe %thing% %path%"
```

The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to escape the % characters **when they're inside double quotes**, but I need the double quotes because of the spaces in this argument. Basically I don't want cmd to do variable expansion before passing the argument value to program.exe.

Just to be clear, this is directly in cmd, not in a batch script.

Comment: Aside from your specific question, your `program.exe` should really be receiving `"otherprogram.exe" "%thing%" "%path%"` i.e each should be quoted to at least protect space characters. Now as we have no idea what `program.exe` or `otherprogram.exe` is, or why you deliberately hid that from us, we cannot tell you if any of those quotes should be escaped. Examples: `-command ""otherprogram.exe" "%thing%" "%path%""`, `-command """otherprogram.exe"" ""%thing%"" ""%path%"""`, `-command "\"otherprogram.exe\" \"%thing%\" \"%path%\""`. Also, please do not create/overwrite the variable named `%path%`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple semi solution is:

```
program.exe -command ^"otherprogram.exe %th^ing% %pa^t^h%^"
```

The positions of the carets inside the variable name are random.

This still could fail, but only for the rare case, if variables exists named `thi^ng` or `pa^t^h`

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange, but don't escape the percent signs. Put a caret (the escape sign for every other special char) anywhere within the variable name: `echo %^username%` or `echo %use^rname%.

The first parsing removes the `^` (because there is (hopefully) no  variable with that name). On command line (other than in a batch file), an empty variable doesn't show nothing, but the variable name including the surrounding `%`'s.

Any further level of parsing then receives the "normal" variable and expands it. Prove:

```
echo %usern^ame%
call echo %usern^ame%
```

Not your question, but for the sake of completeness: in a batch script, simply escape the `%` with another `%`:

```
echo %%username%%
call echo %%username%%
```

Comment: I suppose, the OP already knows that, a problem occurs for the OP, when they are enclosed in quotes